# AngularJS - how to filter on only 1 field and exactly match the query parameter

Tags: angularjs, filter

By default the "filter" in AngularJS filters against all the fields or properties of an object or array, but I want it to filter the data set by exactly comparing a string value in only 1 property of an object.

For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="subCategory in subCategorys | filter:id | orderBy:'id'"></div>
```

where subCategories is a dataset with fields such as "number", "name", "details"... etc.
and I want the filter to only look under "number" property exactly for the parameter used for the query.

For example, look exactly for number 10 in "number" property in subCategorys dataset. and NOT for 010 in "number" field, or sdkjj_10_kjd in "name" or any other field.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks to @sylwester, I now know how to filter for specific value in specific fields. However, this does not work when the parameter value for the filter comes from a route parameter.

Comment: I've a good news and a bad news. Good news: I found that if the filter is applied on numeric values then, this does not work. Bad news: I dont know how to make it work. :( Can you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/zesopa/2/edit

all you need is add third parameter comparator and set it to true value `filter:{id:search_id}:true`

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="search_id" placeholder="search for id">
<div ng-repeat="subCategory in subCategorys | filter:{id:search_id}:true | orderBy:'id'">{{subCategory.id}}</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){

 $scope.subCategorys = [
   {id:1,name:"tom"},
   {id:21,name:"jim"},
   {id:221,name:"pam"}
 ];
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) But what if the object is an array and i have to  look whether the parameter value exists inside this array. For example, see the example @ [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/gugayezi/2/) where i've to look for "cartoon" under "subCategory.tags".

Comment: thanks. it worked :) But my value is coming from another view as a route parameter. so I have to do the following in the controller function.

`$scope.tag = $routeParams.tagID; `

so my filter will look like : 

`filter:{tags:tag}:true` 

BUT this time it doesnt work :(

Comment: @TempOrary please see here http://jsbin.com/yoyoy/3/edit I've set tag inside controller and evrything if fine double check what value you get from $routeParams.tagID;

Comment: yes, I am sure this works. I had already tried this. But the problem arises when you want the value from a URL parameter and pass this parameter to the filter. When I tried this it did not work. It was like the filter was not getting this value. Whereas I was able to display this value on the HTML page using binding. 

PS: I used angular-route.js for routing to get `$routeParams.tag`

Comment: @TempOrary that might helps you  http://plnkr.co/edit/64nqAMIFdfgRIrkqmGeS?p=preview

Comment: I've a good news and a bad news. Good news: I found that if the filter is applied on numeric values then, this does not work. Bad news: I dont know how to make it work. :( Can you please help?

Comment: @TempOrary please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/erUKRD?p=preview beacuse routerparam return string all you nedd is covert it to int  $scope.tag = parseInt($routeParams.tagID)

Comment: Duh! was that it! :O Oh God so silly of me! thank you @sss :)